# ndk-build errors

Tags: android

I built my C++ library with the GCC compiler without any errors in the [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) environment, but when I tried to build [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) files with the library using the *ndk-build* tool, a couple of errors occurred.

One error is missing *iostream.h*, *fstream.h* and *iomanip.h* files. The other one is 'Your C++ compiler cannot handle class templates'.

How can I get around these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the header errors, check out the suggestion here for pulling in more extensive C++ stdlib implementations:

*[Cannot find <iostream>](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/983c436239d48704/90a80cceeb831f97?lnk=gst&q=stl&pli=1)*

As for the class template issue, that doesn't appear to be an error coming from the compiler itself. What are you trying to compile? Maybe it's coming out of an #error directive?